# BottomSheet not transparent on declared "android:background" in styles.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I am in the following situation: I have an app with an white background so I declared the android:background in the styles xml.

**Problem:** I want to show just a basic bottom sheet but I noticed, when the android:background is declared, the bottomsheet is not transparent.

BottomSheet

```
class SortListBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment(){
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sort_list_bottom_sheet, container, false)
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
sortListFab.setOnClickListener {
    val sortListBottomSheet = SortListBottomSheet()
    sortListBottomSheet.show(supportFragmentManager, "test")
}
```

Styles.xml

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

How can I make my bottomSheet transparent?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: use this code for transparent background change background color : https://github.com/Deishelon/RoundedBottomSheet

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution:

Add this to styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
    parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: Use `parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog"` as parent of your `AppBottomSheetDialogTheme`. Also you can declare the style in the `getTheme()` method of your Fragment. The `bottomSheetDialogTheme` attribute changes the style of all the `BottomSheetDialog` in the App.